# Struct.error: argument for 's' must be a bytes object, already supplied

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, struct

I've been working on a TCP/IP connection program thingy in Python and came across the need to use Struct. And so I imported the module and after some time came to a very particular issue. I get the error specified in te title when I run the code below, which should be working after I checked some other answers and documentations.

```
import struct

string = "blab"

s = struct.Struct(b'4s')
packed_data = s.pack(string)

print(packed_data)
```

As far as I found, the issue should be fixed by prepending the string used in the s variable with 'b' or using the `bytes()` function parsing 'utf-8' as encoding argument. Tried both, same error.

I have no idea what might be wrong so am I missing something? I could not find relevant information online regarding this issue, so this is why I'm posting here now.

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance!

Comment: try `str = b"blab"` (watch out for the variable name `string`, there is a core module called `string`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One problem is that you put the "b" in the wrong place. You placed it in the format string, when the data to be packed need to be a byte string.

```
    >>> string = "blab"
    >>> s = struct.Struct('4s')
    >>> packed_data = s.pack(string.encode('utf-8'))
    >>> print(packed_data)
    b'blab'
```

But even that is problematic. Suppose your string is not in the `ascii` character set... let's say it's Greek, then the UTF8 encoded string is more than 4 bytes and you write a truncated value

```
    >>> string = "ΑΒΓΔ"
    >>> s = struct.Struct('4s')
    >>> 
    >>> packed_data = s.pack(string.encode('utf-8'))
    >>> print('utf8len', len(string.encode('utf-8')), 'packedlen', len(packed_data))
    utf8len 8 packedlen 4
    >>> print(packed_data)
    b'\xce\x91\xce\x92'
    >>> print(struct.unpack('4s', packed_data)[0].decode('utf-8'))
    ΑΒ
    >>>
```

If you really need to restrict to 4 bytes, then convert the original string using `ascii` instead of `utf-8` so that any unencodable unicode character will raise an exception right away.

```
    >>> string = "ΑΒΓΔ"
    >>> s = struct.Struct('4s')
    >>> 
    >>> packed_data = s.pack(string.encode('ascii'))
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Oh, I see what the case is now. The main issue came from the fact that the error says argument for 's' which misled me to think that because I have variable 's' to be struct.Struct(...) I thought it meant the argument for s (for struct.Struct(arg) should be a bytes object, and thus misplaced it. Now I double-checked and everything is working fine. Thank you for the feedback and the extra info! Appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

```
packed_data = s.pack(string.encode('utf-8'))
```

Should work in both Py2 and 3

From the Unicode HowTo for Python 2.7.11:

> Another important method is .encode([encoding], [errors='strict']),
>   which returns an 8-bit string version of the Unicode string, encoded
>   in the requested encoding. The errors parameter is the same as the
>   parameter of the unicode() constructor, with one additional
>   possibility; as well as ‘strict’, ‘ignore’, and ‘replace’, you can
>   also pass ‘xmlcharrefreplace’ which uses XML’s character references.
>   The following example shows the different results:

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html